# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Rating'

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is My Html mark up

```
    <form runat="server">

  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" Font-Names = "Arial" Font-Size = "10pt"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataKeyNames="FilePath" >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data='dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=<%#Eval("FilePath") %>'
                width="240" height="20" id="dewplayer">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="movie" value='dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=<%#Eval("FilePath") %>' />
            </object>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Song Ratings">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Rating ID="Rating1"  OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
                StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" CurrentRating='<%# Eval("Rating") %>'>
            </asp:Rating>
        </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField></Columns></asp:GridView></form>
```

This is my aspx.cs file

Binding the ASP.Net GridView

```
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridviewData();


            GridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT SongId, FileName, ISNULL((SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM SongRating WHERE SongId = SongTable.SongId), 0) Rating FROM SongTable");
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }


    }

    private static DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

//Inserting and saving the User Ratings to SQL Server Database Table

```
    protected void OnRatingChanged(object sender, RatingEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = ((sender as Rating).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;
        int songId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SongRating VALUES(@SongId, @Rating)"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SongId", songId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", e.Value);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }



    private void BindGridviewData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from SongTable", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

where is the error occurring i am new to asp.net thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi @abhi you didn't mention the column "Rating" in your select list , do something like this

SELECT SongId, FileName, ISNULL(AVG(Rating),0) as Rating from SongTable left join SongRating on SongRating.SongId = SongTable.SongId group by SongId, FileName

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Sorry,i am not getting it can you please specify the query.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Exception it Says that

> The above exception occurs when a specified data item in the web
>   control does not exist in the schema of the returned DataRowView. In
>   other words the column that you have specified with the databound
>   control is not present in the data returned from database

So probably change your Select  Query  from this in  **BindGridviewData** Method

```
select * from SongTable
```

to this

```
  SELECT SongId, FileName, ISNULL((SELECT AVG(Rating) 
FROM SongRating WHERE SongId = SongTable.SongId), 0) as  Rating FROM SongTable
```